# Cannot mkdir with git clone

Tags: php, linux, git

Once I clone my repo, the folders don't have write access, and so my PHP code cannot use `mkdir()` to make a folder if it needs to.

I get this error:
`mkdir(): Permission denied`

Why is this? In my repo I have a `pages` folder, which has the following permissions after I git clone it to my `/var/www/html` folder.

`drwxr-xr-x 4 me me 4.0K Jun  9 18:30 pages`

Is this set in the repo itself? Or is there some command I can add to `git clone` that will allow me to fix this?

Comment: Try sudo mkdir?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x (or 755) is the default permissions for a folder on linux: readablae, writable and executable by the user; readable and executable by everyone else. If your code is running under a different user, you'll need to update the permissions or ownership to match.

Comment: @rickdenhaan how can I find out what user the php code is running as? is it set in apache2 somewhere?

Comment: It'll be the user Apache is running under in that case. Try `echo get_current_user();` to find out, it'll probably be something like `www-data`

Comment: hmm no it's running as me.  For the record I am just running apache2 on my laptop with Linux Mint.  And I can `mkdir` from the command line.

Comment: What user created the repository? It seems to me that whoever did it was logged in as root... Git tracks even the file permissions, so you should check if it was created wrong, and if so, fix the permissions and `push` the fixed files.

Comment: @GuilhermeCosta I created the repository.  I cant remember if i was logged in as root, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The only file permission that is tracked and handled by Git is the executable bit. Everything else is not tracked and not controlled by Git. This is one of the arguments against using Git as a deployment tool which it is not. You can find some hints on how you can utilize Git to make a deployment strategy at http://gitolite.com/deploy.html. The permssions of the files after cloning are simply the default on your linux system. You can change this in your linux environment to be something different.